# Arduino not responding while trying to flash over BLE

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, bootloader, uploading, atmega2560

I'm working on wireless uploader for Arduino from iOS devices. I'm using HM-10 BLE module which seems to work ok. PIO 2 is used as DTR for resetting (see `A [0x41] T [0x54] + [0x2B] P [0x50] I [0x49] O [0x4F] 2 [0x32] 1 [0x31]` and `A [0x41] T [0x54] + [0x2B] P [0x50] I [0x49] O [0x4F] 2 [0x32] 0 [0x30]` below)- using 0.1uF capacitor and 10K resistor wired to MCU reset pin. Reset seems to be done correctly as i'm getting `ready` output (in 'setup()' body in uploaded sketch).

For some reason i'm getting `0x14 0x10` for `0x30 0x20` request (to ping bootloader) but not getting response for `A [0x41] . [0x81]   [0x20]` within almost 1 second.

Uploading over BLE:

```
2015-07-04 19:24:10.955 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: A [0x41] T [0x54] + [0x2B] P [0x50] I [0x49] O [0x4F] 2 [0x32] 1 [0x31] 
2015-07-04 19:24:10.955 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: BLE sending bytes range from 0 length 8
2015-07-04 19:24:11.106 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 8 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:11.106 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: A [0x41] T [0x54] + [0x2B] P [0x50] I [0x49] O [0x4F] 2 [0x32] 0 [0x30] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.106 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: BLE sending bytes range from 0 length 8
2015-07-04 19:24:11.148 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [   ]: Draining for 230 ms ...
2015-07-04 19:24:11.148 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Start reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.323 xctest[54864:5122903] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Rx value received 9 bytes: O [0x4F] K [0x4B] + [0x2B] P [0x50] I [0x49] O [0x4F] 2 [0x32] : [0x3A] 1 [0x31] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.323 xctest[54864:5122903] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Rx value received 9 bytes: O [0x4F] K [0x4B] + [0x2B] P [0x50] I [0x49] O [0x4F] 2 [0x32] : [0x3A] 0 [0x30] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.381 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Finish reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.381 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Ble clear buffer
2015-07-04 19:24:11.381 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Drained 18 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:11.381 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 2 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:11.381 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: 0 [0x30]   [0x20] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.382 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: BLE sending bytes range from 0 length 2
2015-07-04 19:24:11.382 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Reading 1 bytes ...
2015-07-04 19:24:11.382 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Start reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.746 xctest[54864:5122914] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Rx value received 1 bytes: . [0x00] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.747 xctest[54864:5122914] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Ignoring single 0x00 char 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.747 xctest[54864:5122914] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Rx value received 2 bytes: . [0x14] . [0x10] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.748 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Finish reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.748 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Receive: . [0x14] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.749 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Read 1 bytes, actually received 2 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:11.749 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: 1 bytes in incoming buffer remaining for next receive
2015-07-04 19:24:11.749 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Reading 1 bytes ...
2015-07-04 19:24:11.750 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Having current receive buffer: . [0x10] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.750 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Start reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.750 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Finish reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.751 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Receive: . [0x10] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.751 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Read 1 bytes, actually received 1 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:11.751 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Ble clear buffer
2015-07-04 19:24:11.752 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 3 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:11.752 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: A [0x41] . [0x81]   [0x20] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.752 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: BLE sending bytes range from 0 length 3
2015-07-04 19:24:11.752 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Reading 1 bytes ...
2015-07-04 19:24:11.753 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Start reading
2015-07-04 19:24:11.821 xctest[54864:5122914] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Rx value received 1 bytes: . [0x00] 
2015-07-04 19:24:11.821 xctest[54864:5122914] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Ignoring single 0x00 char 
2015-07-04 19:24:12.721 xctest[54864:5122903] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Rx value received 5 bytes: r [0x72] e [0x65] a [0x61] d [0x64] y [0x79] 
2015-07-04 19:24:12.722 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Finish reading
2015-07-04 19:24:12.722 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Receive: r [0x72] 
2015-07-04 19:24:12.723 xctest[54864:5122867] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Read 1 bytes, actually received 5 bytes
2015-07-04 19:24:12.723 xctest[54864:5122867] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: 4 bytes in incoming buffer remaining for next receive
2015-07-04 19:24:12.723 xctest[54864:5122867] [ERROR  ] [   ]: STK500:getParameter: protocol error #1, expected [0x14], received [0x72]
```

When uploading over usb it's ok:

```
2015-06-29 16:34:10.829 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [   ]: DTR/RTS supported by Serial, resetting
2015-06-29 16:34:11.140 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Draining ...
2015-06-29 16:34:11.392 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Drain done
2015-06-29 16:34:11.392 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 2 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.392 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: 0 [0x30]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.393 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.531 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.531 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.532 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.532 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 3 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.532 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: A [0x41] . [0x81]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.533 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.535 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.536 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.536 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x04] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.536 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.536 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.537 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 3 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.537 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: A [0x41] . [0x82]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.537 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.540 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.540 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.540 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x04] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.540 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.541 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.541 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [   ]: STK500:initialize: n_extparms = 4
2015-06-29 16:34:11.541 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 22 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.542 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: B [0x42] . [0x86] . [0x00] . [0x01] . [0x00] . [0x01] . [0x01] . [0x01] . [0x03] . [0xFF] . [0xFF] . [0xFF] . [0xFF] . [0x00] . [0x80] . [0x04] . [0x00] . [0x00] . [0x00] . [0x80] . [0x00]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.542 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.548 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.548 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.548 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.548 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 7 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.549 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: E [0x45] . [0x05] . [0x04] . [0xD7] . [0xC2] . [0x00]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.549 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.552 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.552 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.552 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.553 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 2 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.553 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: P [0x50]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.553 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.556 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.556 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 1 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.556 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.569 xctest[36585:3703900] Reading |                                                    | 0% 0ms
2015-06-29 16:34:11.570 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [OUT]: Sending 2 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.571 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [OUT]: Send: u [0x75]   [0x20] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.571 xctest[36585:3703900] [DEBUG  ] [IN ]: Receiving 5 bytes
2015-06-29 16:34:11.572 xctest[36585:3703900] [TRACE  ] [IN ]: Received: . [0x14] . [0x1E] . [0x95] . [0x0F] . [0x10] 
2015-06-29 16:34:11.572 xctest[36585:3703900] Reading | ################################################## | 100% 2ms
```

So when uploading over USB DTR/RTS and [similar schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61537/what-is-the-cap-for-in-arduino-reset-circuit) is used.

I think the problem is in resetting approach - wiring to reset does not work when trying to upload. Am i right? Is it bootloader issue?

PS. Arduino sketch uploaded:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("ready");

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: I forgot to say i've tested with Arduino Uno r3. i've just tested uploading to Arduino Mega2560 and it works - Mega's bootloader replies as expected and uploading succeed. What's wrong with Uno?